# Convert SimpleDateFormat to DateTimeFormatter

Tags: java, java-8, simpledateformat, datetime-format

So when trying to replace some legacy code using SimpleDateFormat and Date, to use java.time.DateTimeFormatter and LocalDate I ran into a problem. The two date formats are not equivalent. At this point I must say I know the two date types are not the same but the scenario I am in means I never care about the time aspect so can ignore it.

```
public Date getDate(String value) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    try {
        return dateFormat.parse(value);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        return null;
    }
}

public LocalDate getLocalDate(String value) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
    try {
        return LocalDate.parse(value, formatter);
    } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
        return null;
    }
}

public void testDates() {
    getDate("03/07/2016");               // Sun Jul 03 00:00:00 BST 2016
    getDate("3/7/2016");                 // Sun Jul 03 00:00:00 BST 2016
    getDate("3/7/2016 00:00:00");        // Sun Jul 03 00:00:00 BST 2016
    getDate("3/7/2016 00:00:00.0+0100"); // Sun Jul 03 00:00:00 BST 2016
    getDate("3/7/2016T00:00:00.0+0100"); // Sun Jul 03 00:00:00 BST 2016

    getLocalDate("03/07/2016");               // 2016-07-03
    getLocalDate("3/7/2016");                 // null
    getLocalDate("3/7/2016 00:00:00");        // null
    getLocalDate("3/7/2016 00:00:00.0+0100"); // null
    getLocalDate("3/7/2016T00:00:00.0+0100"); // null
}
```

As you can see when the same pattern is used in both formatters the DateTimeFormatter ends up producing nulls where you'd expect to see dates equivalent to that of SDF. In this scenario I would expect the unrequired data to be dropped but it isn't.

So, how do we create a robust date/time parser?!

Comment: I don't think the `SimpleDateFormat` is more robust, because `dd/MM/yyyy` requires clearly 2 digits for the day of month, 2 digits for the month, and 4 digits for the year. If your input does not match this requirement, the framework should raise a parse exception. Doing a conversion different from user requirement is dangerous.

Comment: Yes SDF broken - but the code relies on this. So in general I would completely agree an API should have a fixed format and only accept that however in this scenario we are parsing files and people can provide dates in a variety of formats; the code needs to cater for them all. Obviously this is just an excerpt of the problem faced, in fact there are a whole lot more checks it does around date ordering and separators.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

So there may be other answers to this but what I came up caters for the most extreme case I have. Firstly I reduced dd/MM to d/M. This denotes the minimum number of expected characters so will parse double digits completely fine. Note you could also use new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().parseLenient() but this seemed unnecessary.

Secondly I decided to use the optional clause in the format pattern itself. This allows you to specify which parts may not be provided which is exactly the case I was trying to solve.

Leaving us with:

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d/M/yyyy[' ']['T'][H:mm[:ss[.S]]][X]");
```

This will now handle providing a date with or without time including a T separator, seconds, millis and zone offset.

With any luck this helps someone else!

```
private DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d/M/yyyy[' ']['T'][H:mm[:ss[.S]]][X]");

public LocalDate getRobustLocalDate(String value) {
    try {
        return LocalDate.parse(value, formatter);
    } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
        return null;
    }
}

@Test
public void testDates() {
    getRobustLocalDate("03/07/2016");               // 2016-07-03
    getRobustLocalDate("3/7/2016");                 // 2016-07-03
    getRobustLocalDate("3/7/2016 00:00:00");        // 2016-07-03
    getRobustLocalDate("3/7/2016 00:00:00.0+0100"); // 2016-07-03
    getRobustLocalDate("3/7/2016T00:00:00.0+0100"); // 2016-07-03
}
```

Comment: You actually don't need to initialize `DateTimeFormatter` each time you call a method: since instances of `DateTimeFormatter` class are immutable, you can save them outside of the method and reuse, saving a little on object generation and pattern parsing. Your pattern will not change, so I feel this might be valid adjustment to make.

Comment: Yep - totally agree, it was just like this for the purpose of the test. Will edit to make it clearer to others