# DateFormat To DateTimeFormatter

Tags: java, date-format

I can get rid of this issue, and i don't found the answer rigth now.

Is it possible to convert DateFormat on DateTimeFormatter?

```
DateFormat dateFormat =  new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault);
```

I want to make something like that :

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern((String)dateFormatter);
```

Or

```
(DateTimeFormatter)dateFormatter;
```

Or is there a way to get the String that make the format in the DateFormat?

I want to do that beacause i've read that the DateTimeFormater is the Java8+ new way to deal with Date, and i need to keep the old one because it's used a lot of times elswhere in the Project.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just do `DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss")`? You could apply a `static final String format = "MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss"` and use it for both, the old fashioned and the modern way.

Comment: Well because it's not static, so i need to be in the case of the user preferences etc... The first line of code is an exemple, i dont put it in hard

Comment: OK, then you could just get the `String` from some user preference... Show us where the source is in your code, please.

Comment: Closely related: [Convert SimpleDateFormat to DateTimeFormatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42903391/convert-simpledateformat-to-datetimeformatter).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use following code.

```
 DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(((SimpleDateFormat) dateFormat).toPattern());
```

Comment: It wil generally work, but there are corner cases where it doesn’t. Not all format pattern letters have exactly the same meaning, in particular the number of letters may impose a meaning in `DateTimeFormatter` that they hadn’t necessarily got in `DateFormat`. But it’s probably the best we can do. See [Convert SimpleDateFormat to DateTimeFormatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42903391/convert-simpledateformat-to-datetimeformatter).

Comment: Thanks a lot, i didn't thouth that you could use a `DateFormat` as a `SimpleDateFormat` without loosing some datas. And in this case i dont care about the Letters so the issues reported by Ole isn't a problem for me.

Comment: In theory your `DateFormat` may not be a `SimpleDateFormat`, and if it isn’t, this code will crash. In practice I doubt that this will happen, though.

Comment: If the locale of your `DateFormat` may be something else than the default, you probably want to transfer it to your `DateTimeFormatter` too. Since it is pretty straightforward, I will leave it as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: It is but it can be change at anytime in the running, and it alredy change the `DateFormat`, so i thouth that is will be ligther to just transfer the change on the `DateTimeFormatter`